# Matlab convert form hex to float

Tags: matlab

I'm working with a device that send to me hex values, and I need convert those values to his real float value. Someone know how to convert from hex values to float in matlab?

Thx

Comment: Give more details, and possibly a small example. Do you have those hex values in a variable already? Maximum value? Desired output data type?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [hex2dec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html), to convert your hex to decimal.

Hex format is inherently integer (the floating point position is not defined), so you will have to give more info: Does the hex represent a mantissa-exponent floating point number? Does it represent a fixed-point number?

Answer (score 0):

the hex represent a mantissa-exponent floating point number. for exemple 0x44ADE000 equal to 1391.0